# C - Segmentation Fault: Core Dumped (waitpid)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a `Segmentation Fault: Core Dumped`. I used GDB to debug my C program. I backtraced the error to that line :

```
waitpid(chpid, &status, WUNTRACED);
```

The program executes a command in a child process. It listens for Control-z and stops the job when it is pressed (with `kill`).

```
chpid = fork();             

if (chpid == 0) {           /* Inside the child */
  /* Execute the command with the options */
  status = execvp(args[0], args);  

  /* Exit with status */
  exit(status);
} else {                  /* Inside the parent */

    /* wait for child to finish */
    /* save the exit status of the child inside status */
--> waitpid(chpid, &status, WUNTRACED);

    if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
      kill(chpid, SIGCONT);
```

Does the segmentation fault at line --> means that the function `waitpid` cause the error, or was it caused by the child process?

**COMPLETE MINIMAL PROGRAM**

```
pid_t chpid;

void handle_SIGTSTP()
{
  /* put chpid into the background */
  kill(chpid, SIGSTOP);
}

int main(void)
{
  /* don't forget, pid_t chpid was defined globally */
  int status = 0;                 /* filled on child's exit */

  /* Ignore CTRL-C */
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

  /* set up the signal handler for <C-z> */
  struct sigaction handler;
  handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGTSTP;
  sigaction(SIGTSTP, &handler, NULL);

  while (1) {                 /* Proram terminates normally inside setup */
    background = 0;
    printf("COMMAND->\n");

    if (!setup(inputBuffer, args, &background)) {    /* get next command */
      continue;
    }

    /* FORK PROCESS ----------------- */
    /* Create a child by calling fork */
    chpid = fork();             

    if (chpid == 0) {           /* Inside the child */
      /* Execute the command with the options */
      status = execvp(args[0], args);  

      /* Exit with status */
      exit(status);
    } else {                  /* Inside the parent */

        /* wait for child to finish */
        /* save the exit status of the child inside status */
        waitpid(chpid, &status, WUNTRACED);

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
          kill(chpid, SIGCONT);

    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I replace

```
struct sigaction handler;
handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGTSTP;
sigaction(SIGTSTP, &handler, NULL);
```

by

```
signal(SIGTSTP, &handle_SIGTSTP);
```

The segmentation error is gone, but CTRL-Z is not caught on first press...

**UPDATE 2**

Just after the while loop, I compare the value of `args[0]`. It seems that this is causing the issue :

```
 if (strcmp(args[0], "history") == 0) {
```

How canI I modify that?

Comment: How is `status` declared ?

Comment: Simply as `int status = 0;`.

Comment: And what is it `execvp`ing ?

Comment: I use `find /` for my tests. I also tried `ls -R `. `grep` gives the same same result`.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with it. Can you post a complete minimal program ?

Comment: where is `args` defined?

Comment: args is defined in main. I forgot to include it : `char *args[MAX_LINE]`.

Comment: You're not initializing `handler` completely. Can you `memset` it to 0 before assigning `handle_SIGTSTP` ?

Comment: Like so : `memset(&handler, 0, 1)`?

Comment: I removed `WIFSTOPPED` and now the seg fault is gone... Any hint why? Maybe status is not set for some reason...?

Comment: @JustinD. No, `memset(&handler, 0, sizeof handler)`. The `WIFSTOPPED` check is required.

Comment: Thanks! Using `memset` seems to have done the trick! (I kept `WIFSTOPPED`). (You can answer the question so I can accept it if you want).

Comment: @JustinD. I think it's better if you answer the question and explain what was going on :-)

Comment: @cnicutar, I wanted to give you some points, but with your 86K, I don't think you care about 10 points ;-)